# Spring Xd no containers available for stream

Tags: spring, spring-xd

I'm running Spring XD in distributed mode.  But when I bring up a container the admin node sees it and only deploys some and not all streams.  Here is the admin log

```
             :11:41+0000 1.3.0.RELEASE INFO DeploymentSupervisor-0 zk.ContainerListener - Container arrived: Container{name='26c5cbfa-7f20-455c-a36c-580c98a8126--More--(76%)
...skipping 1 line
2016-10-03T19:11:41+0000 1.3.0.RELEASE INFO DeploymentSupervisor-0 zk.ContainerListener - Scheduling deployments to new container(s) in 15000 ms
2016-10-03T19:11:57+0000 1.3.0.RELEASE INFO DeploymentSupervisor-0 zk.ModuleRedeployer - Deployment state for stream 'cameras-http-receiver': DeploymentStatus{state=incomplete}
2016-10-03T19:11:57+0000 1.3.0.RELEASE WARN DeploymentSupervisor-0 zk.ModuleRedeployer - No containers available for redeployment of http for stream cameras-http-receiver
2016-10-03T19:11:57+0000 1.3.0.RELEASE INFO DeploymentSupervisor-0 zk.ModuleRedeployer - Deployment state for stream 'cameras-http-receiver': DeploymentStatus{state=incomplete}
2016-10-03T19:11:59+0000 1.3.0.RELEASE INFO DeploymentSupervisor-0 zk.ModuleRedeployer - Deployment state for stream 'cameras-http-receiver-2': DeploymentStatus{state=deployed}
2016-10-03T19:12:00+0000 1.3.0.RELEASE INFO DeploymentSupervisor-0 zk.ModuleRedeployer - Deployment state for stream 'cameras-http-receiver-3': DeploymentStatus{state=deployed}
2016-10-03T19:12:01+0000 1.3.0.RELEASE INFO DeploymentSupervisor-0 zk.ModuleRedeployer - Deployment state for stream 'cameras-processor': DeploymentStatus{state=deployed}
2016-10-03T19:12:02+0000 1.3.0.RELEASE INFO DeploymentSupervisor-0 zk.ModuleRedeployer - Deployment state for stream 'cameras-to-mongo': DeploymentStatus{state=incomplete}

...skipping 1 line
2016-10-03T19:12:02+0000 1.3.0.RELEASE INFO DeploymentSupervisor-0 zk.ModuleRedeployer - Deployment state for stream 'cameras-to-mongo': DeploymentStatus{state=incomplete}
2016-10-03T19:12:03+0000 1.3.0.RELEASE INFO DeploymentSupervisor-0 zk.ModuleRedeployer - Deployment state for stream 'mongo-sink': DeploymentStatus{state=incomplete}
2016-10-03T19:12:03+0000 1.3.0.RELEASE WARN DeploymentSupervisor-0 zk.ModuleRedeployer - No containers available for redeployment of mongodb for stream mongo-sink
2016-10-03T19:12:03+0000 1.3.0.RELEASE INFO DeploymentSupervisor-0 zk.ModuleRedeployer - Deployment state for stream 'mongo-sink': DeploymentStatus{state=incomplete}
```

Why is it saying there's no containers available right after it recognizes the container?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any container matching criteria for the modules? It looks like one of the module instances fails to get deployed while the ModuleRedeployer is looking for some other container to deploy that module.